# Regular expression Javascript match letters except one

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to improve my regular expression in order to not match this string when it has a `D` in it:

```
www.google.com/.../DE69619938D1?cl=e
```

My regex :

```
(DE)([0-9]{1,12})((?:[ABCUT][0-9]?)?)
```

1. I want to match when "D1" is missing: that's why I put a `?` after this group. (working)
2. I want to match when the letter is A B C U or T. (working)
3. But when it is a `D` after the numbers I don't want to match the string and I don't know how to make this without losing the first rule.

Comment: When D is there you dont wanna match.Then why is D in your regex?

Comment: `.indexOf("D") === -1` and then regex?

Comment: I mean the second "D"

Comment: You don't want to match the second "D", then what do your first rule mean?

Comment: I want to match when the link is like this : www.google.com/.../DE69619938?cl=e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
(DE)([0-9]{1,12})(?:(?:[ABCUT][0-9]?)|\?)
```